# Targeting category css

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

In wordpress I have an article in my `content.php` which creates a grid of images out of the `featured-thumbnail` of posts. This snippet of code puts the post title `(the_title();)` and the category title `(the_category(', '))`

**HTML**:

```
<div class="title-styling">
   <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1></a>
   <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?> "><h2><?php the_category(', '); ?></h2></a>
</div>
```

I want to target the css attributes of `the_category(', ')` text like change colour padding etc. But my CSS doesn't seem to affect it (especially colour), even with `!important` added.

**CSS**  (attempts that did not work):

```
.title-styling > h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font: 500 15px/10px "Open Sans";
}

.title-styling h2 {
 color: #fff;
 font: 500 15px/10px "Open Sans";
}
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean? as in put the <h2> right outside the a?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following

```
.title-styling > a > h2.title-category {
  color: #fff;
  font: 500 15px/10px "Open Sans";
}
```

And this if you want to remove the underline of the anchor tag (link) **[optional]**

```
.title-styling > a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Try giving a class to the h2 tag to target it more specifically

```
<div class="title-styling">
   <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1></a>
   <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?> "><h2 class="title-category"><?php the_category(', '); ?></h2></a>
</div>
```

Comment: it doesn't change the attributes even with !important added.

Comment: what about if you add a class to the `h2`

Comment: a mix of what you mentioned seems to be doing something, but I had to remove title-category, and switch it to .title-styling > h2 > a, and add a seperate .title-styling h2 style

Answer (score 0):

> represent it parent must .title-styling

try below:

```
.title-styling  h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font: 500 15px/10px "Open Sans";
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't mention this earlier, That was my first attempt which did not work. The one I listed above, Is an idea I was given by someone which did not work either